# Add/get value from Database MVC4 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating a feature which allows a user to add an certain amount of money to a 'Swiss bank'. The balance of the swiss bank is stored in the `db` (`id`and `balance`) for each user. I'm stuck on how to display the current balance of the user and how to add or witdraw an amount of money. I'm very new on `c#`and `mvc4` so help is really appreciated (just a push in the right direction would be awesome).

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using FiveGangs.Models;

namespace FiveGangs.Controllers {
public class BankController : Controller {
    private FGEntities db = new FGEntities();
    //
    // GET: /SwissBank/

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var gangster =
            db.UserGangster.FirstOrDefault(g => g.UserProfile.UserName == User.Identity.Name && g.Health > 0);
    }

    public ActionResult Index() {
        return View(db.SwissBank);
    }

}
}
```

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace FiveGangs.Models
{
public partial class SwissBank {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Balance { get; set; }
 }
 }
```

View:

```
    @using FiveGangs.Models
    @model System.Data.Entity.DbSet<SwissBank>

    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Bank";
    }

<h2>Bank</h2>

<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Swiss Bank</legend>
      <label>Balance: @String.Format("{0:C0}", @Model.Balance)</label>
      <span class="add-on">$</span>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Amount...">
      <span class="help-block">Withdrawing from your Swiss bank will cost you 25% of the amount of cash withdrawn!</span>
     <button class="btn" type="button">Deposit</button>
  <button class="btn" type="button">Withdraw</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you designed the database tables to store the account informations

Comment: Here are a few steps,

 1. You create a model to represent the account [Account Id]
 2. Your account model will have userId, Amt_Withdrawl, Amt_Deposit, Amt_balance etc... where the Amt_balance is a calculated property.
 3. When you are trying to get the user's balance amount, you will just call the query that returns based on the UserId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Create a Action Method for Create.

```
public ActionResult Create() {
    return View();
}
```

Step 2: Add View with same name

Step 3: Add Another Action Method to receive post data and save

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(SwissBank swisBank) {
    if(ModelState.Isvalid)
    {
        db.SwisBank.Add(swisBank);
        db.SaceChanges()
    }
    return View();
}
```

Read this documents:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application

It will help you.

Comment: Thanks, this got me further!